# $compile is only properly inserting my template the first time that I run it

Tags: angularjs

http://embed.plnkr.co/SPGNLd0bcmo2Xt2TAZcB/preview

Here we have a list of personnel information cards.  If you click on one, the directive triggers a template to be loaded between that row and the row before it.  My problem is that it only works once!

I believe that my problem lies somewhere in my compile statement, but I'm not sure:

```
$compile(controller.former)(scope);
```

What honestly baffles me is that even if you just click on the same card over and over again, ignoring all the others, it still just loads the one time.  After the first successful load, the Template insertion is coming up empty.  that is, isntead of the full template being inserted, i'm just getting:

```
<!-- ngInclude: 'focus.html' -->
```

And not the actual template located in that file.  Does anybody have any Idea what is going on here?

I apologize in advance for the relatively complex directive, if anybody has any suggestions for refactoring it, I am an open book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
controller.former = angular.element('<div ng-include="\'focus.html\'"></div>');
```

to:

```
controller.former = angular.element('<div><div ng-include="\'focus.html\'"></div></div>');
```

By wrapping the template into a parent container, I ensure that `controller.former` is always a reference to a container that holds all of the elements generated during compile time.  without this fix, sometimes `controller.former` would only be selecting the comment node that precedes the inserted material.  This resolves causes problems when i'm passing that selector into `$animate.enter` or `$animate.leave,`  because it ends up only trying to animate that single comment node and ignoring it's next sibling.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem I described is in async manner of getting the template from the server side. In case of cached content it didn't work. You used element bind to click which is anti-angular way and non-angular context (thus you needed yo call $apply). And in this case I guess the problem that $scope.apply works before the content of the compiled node itself is processed (because you get the template immediately from the cache). If you call $scope.apply from the $timeout function or (better) change the function to scope function linked with templates via ng-click it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the goal are are going to achieve you are taken a bit wrong design which looks a bit weird. Anyway I can show you the problem - you are using separate template which is compiled inside of the ng-include. ng-include directive actually performs $http request with using template cache (default behavior) because of this the data is loaded only once and the template isn't inserted. If you add random seed to the template URL or make $templateCache.remove('focus.html') before compiling that can solve your issue (but I don't think it's good solution as it makes http call each time). You should definitely re-factor your code to make it more clean.

Comment: the problem is not with caching, `ngInclude` works well with cached templates. Totally agree about refactoring though.

Comment: I know that ngInclude works fine with cached templates but in this particular case removing the template from the cache before re-compiling works fine. But I am not 100% sure why it happens. It may be compilation issue or the impact of async loading of the template first time which changes behavior against the other attempts... I just mentioned the problem I found.